# exporting table structure to Excel files with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I' going to create an excel file from my table structure in Phpmyadmin(structure only).I found that it has a CSV output but it gives me just data.
Does Phpmyadmin has any feature to do such a thing or not?

Edit:
it's my sql :

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'c://wamp/my_table_structure.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'dt_user'
```

why it return an empty file?

Comment: which version of phpmyadmin you are using?

Comment: you mean your current table to excel file (`.xls`) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could run a [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html) query along the following lines:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/my_table_structure.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
```

Comment: should I specify the database or not?just change the my_table?

Comment: @hamedkh: The [`DATABASE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_database) function returns the name of the currently selected database.  If you have the database containing `my_table` currently selected, you can just use that function as stated above; otherwise replace it with a string literal, e.g. `'my_db'`.

Comment: @hamedkh: Did you try explicitly naming the database too?

Comment: thanks it does work...is there any way to get just column?i just need them.

Comment: @hamedkh: `SELECT COLUMN_NAME INTO OUTFILE ...`

Comment: @eggyal  As you have mentioned I tried this code in PHP to export tb1 to an excel sheet when the user is Admin . `if($level==1){
 echo "<br>";
 $q9=<<<QUERY
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/sheet1.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE('db1') AND TABLE_NAME ='tb1'
QUERY;
$s9=mysql_query($q9,$connect) or die("couldn't add values");
 }` But nothing gets into `sheet1.csv`

Comment: @eggyal does this gets affected by sessions? Also is there any changes I have to make in Excel in order for the data to be inserted?

Comment: add TABLE_NAME like '%' and get the schema for the entire database

Comment: In the export csv file the sequence will be in: **def, database name, table name, column name, column count, default value, null, type, char min length, char max length, int min length, int max length, collation, collation details, type & length, key/ indexs, extras (like auto_increment), data manipulation, comment**

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I achieved with the combination of PHPMyadmin and a chrome plugin. This might not be the straightforward way but it just works. 
(Assuming you are using Google Chrome)

- Install Table capture for chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/table-capture/iebpjdmgckacbodjpijphcplhebcmeop/related?hl=en
- Once the plugin is installed, open PHPmyadmin > DB > table > click on Structure
- Right cLick on Print View > open in a new tab( this is important as the chrome plugin doesn't work on tables in an iframe)

[image]

- once the print view opens in a new tab, click on the plugin icon in the address bar,

[image]

- Click on the plugin icon and you will be shown options to either copy table to clipboard or export to Google docs.

[image]

- I did a copy and pasted the table into excel. You can also export to google docs.

[image]

Note: This is just a workaround and just wanted to share this. Please be easy on comments & TD's :) , and I like the way proposed by eggyal anyways!

Comment: copy pasting the print view directly into LibreOffice made it for me without chrome plugin, thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a plugin to copy and paste to Excel.

1. In phpmyadmin select the table you want to export the schema from
2. Click on Print View at the bottom of the page
3. Select the entire (or partial) table and click ctrl-c to copy
4. Open a new Excel worksheet and select the first cell
5. Click ctrl-v to paste

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, phpmyadmin has an export format called CSV for Microsoft Excel, which makes it all automatically, you just need to click export on a table view and choose the format.

Answer (score 1):

In phpMyAdmin find your table and then select the Export tab
[image: In your table select tab Export]

Select Format CSV for MS Ecel
[image: Select Format CSV for MS Excel]

Just open a new Excel file, then click Data tab and then From Text/CSV and find the file you created in phpMyAdmin.Then click Load. Excel will create the columns just like the table in your data base, you can modify the delimiters if needed.
[image: Select tab Data and then From Text/CSV and then find your csv file]

Answer (score 0):

extending the [eggyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623041/eggyal) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399530/16457439) to all tables on an entire DB

mysql code:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/my_table_structure.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM   information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'the_db_to_export' AND TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'the_db_to_export')
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC;
```

NB: information_schema can be lower case or upper case depends on your installation